# $\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$ regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, references

The naive approach to a $\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$ regression problem is simply to solve $n$ distinct $\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}$ regression problems. However, suppose that the output of the regressor $f:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$ must satisfy some constraint, such as lying on some manifold or belonging to some convex set. Have such regression problems been studied? Pointers to theoretical results much welcome.

[Previously posted at cstheory, now deleted from there.]

Comment: You may find the discussion in R's `systemfit` package vignette useful.

Comment: This is called **multivariate multiple regression**

Comment: I am interested in theoretical results—any pointers?

Comment: The restriction to lie on a (non-affine) manifold is extremely broad, because perforce it makes this a *nonlinear* regression problem.  These things are studied one at a time because their behaviors can be so incredibly varied.